# Can a database row be deleted if a file is moved into a different destination?

Tags: php

I have a file which can possibly be moved into either 2 places depending on which button the user clicked on a seperate page:

At the moment I have stated if the the file moves into 'ImageFiles' folder then move the folder and insert a database row.

But I want to also include that if the file hasn't been uploaded into 'ImageFiles' folder, then delete database row using this code below:

```
$imagecancelsql = "DELETE FROM Image 
                   WHERE ImageFile = 'ImageFiles/".
                   mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['fileImage']['name'])."'";
mysql_query($imagecancelsql);
```

Is this possible to do and if so how can it be written in the current if/else statement I have in the php script?

Below is php script:

```
<?php

session_start();


...//connect to DB

$result = 0;

if( is_file("ImageFiles/".$_FILES['fileImage']['name'])) {
$parts = explode(".",$_FILES['fileImage']['name']);
$ext = array_pop($parts);
$base = implode(".",$parts);
$n = 2;

while( is_file("ImageFiles/".$base."_".$n.".".$ext)) $n++;
$_FILES['fileImage']['name'] = $base."_".$n.".".$ext;

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileImage"]["tmp_name"],
    "ImageFiles/" . $_FILES["fileImage"]["name"]);
    $result = 1;

    $imagesql = "INSERT INTO Image (ImageFile) 
    VALUES ('ImageFiles/".mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['fileImage']['name'])."')";

    mysql_query($imagesql);

}
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileImage"]["tmp_name"],
      "ImageFiles/" . $_FILES["fileImage"]["name"]);
      $result = 1;

        $imagesql = "INSERT INTO Image (ImageFile) 
        VALUES ('ImageFiles/".mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['fileImage']['name'])."')";

mysql_query($imagesql);

      }
```

Comment: How do you move your file from one folder to another? If this happens when file is already uploaded to the directory that is written in DB, so you've got event when file moves, so at this time you can delete your note.

Comment: @PLB What I have done is that the user can cancel an upload, when the user does this, it removes the iframe meaning that the file will not be uploaded into ImageFiles folder. That is why I am trying to say that if file is not uploaded into ImageFiles, then delete the database row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood correctly, the following code should work as intended. If the file has been found, the new file will replce it and inserts a new entry to your database.
If the file wasnt found, the database entry will be removed from you table.

```
// Stores the final result
// 0 = File wasnt uploaded and the row has been removed from table
// 1 = File was uploaded and the row has added to the table
$result = 0;
if (is_file("ImageFiles/" . $_FILES['fileImage']['name'])) {
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileImage"]["tmp_name"], "ImageFiles/" . $_FILES["fileImage"]["name"]);

    $imagesql = "INSERT INTO Image (ImageFile) VALUES ('ImageFiles/".mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['fileImage']['name'])."')";
    mysql_query($imagesql);

    // Mark result as 1 - we have added the file to teh folder and a entry to the table
    $result = 1;
} else {
    $imagecancelsql = "DELETE FROM Image WHERE ImageFile = 'ImageFiles/" . mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['fileImage']['name'])."'";
    mysql_query($imagecancelsql);
}
```

Comment: Hi, sorry I have not included full code but if you look at full code, I have an if statement for if file exists, and an else statement if file doesn't exist, in your answer it will need to be restructured a bit differently to match with mine.